# Is there a way to retrieve calendar appointments from Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a business page where customers can block an appointment at a specified time. It is shown in the "Appointments" section of the page.
Is there a way I can retrieve this using Graph API?

I've tried using the "conversations" in API since the "Inbox" section also shows the customer's request for the appointment.
But the "message" field is coming empty in the API

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page lists `messaging_appointments` as one of the fields you can subscribe to for webhook updates, but I am not sure if that is even related, can’t find anything more about it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/pages-developer-tools: _“If you're already working with small and medium businesses to help manage their appointment bookings and customer orders, we're in early stages of creating new developer tools that enable you to power these experiences on Pages.”_ - but that’s a limited beta you have to apply for.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/10/19/rich-experiences-facebook-pages/